# MS SQL 2008 R2 : Manual increment column based on count of another column (like depth)

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi All,

This is my table (MyTable) structure:

Col1        Col2      Col3       Col4

a              c             e

a             c               f

a             c              g

b             d             h

b             d             i

b             d             j

b             d             k

(Col 1, 2 and 3 are uniqueidentifier, Col4
is an Int)

 

I need to increment (or decrement) Col4
based on same values grouped in Col2 for each Col3 values:

Col1       Col2       Col3       Col4

a              c             e             1

a              c              f              2

a              c             g             3

b              d             h             1

b              d             i              2

b               d             j              3

b              d             k             4

 

Someone have an idea?

 

Best Regards,

 

Carl.

Comment: You want to select or update table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

To **select**:

```
SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col3) as Col4
FROM TableName
```

To **update** the table:

```
UPDATE T1
SET Col4 = T2.RN
FROM
    TableName T1 JOIN
    (SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col3) as RN
     FROM TableName) T2 ON T1.Col1=T2.Col1 AND T1.Col2=T2.Col2 AND T1.Col3=T2.Col3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Update' for changing data, 'case when' to select your case.

```
Example:
update MyTable (Col4) values (case when Col3='e' then Col4+1 else Col4) 
// increments Col4 if Col3 is 'e' and leaves it as it is if not 'e'
```